# What food am I making?

Tags: lateral-thinking, real

I was planning to make two portions, but didn't have enough potable water.

Then I decided to make four portions, and the water was plentiful.

**What food was I making?**

---

Hint 1:

> I have half a liter of water.

Hint 2:

> I have half a liter of *potable* water.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, it may be my specialty dish

> **boiled potatoes** - only 2 in a pot did not raise the water level high enough, but with 4 the water covered the spuds, without one having to turn them over. **Pot**able water is especially important if these are peeled before boiling - something I wouldn't do.

The above is updated after an original more complicated dish

> **poached eggs** - having 4 instead of 2 may keep the eggs surrounded by water. It's best to use drinkable water for this.

Comment: Not the answer I was thinking, but close!

Comment: @jpa -  If it’s similar like my specialty rot13(obvyvat cbgngbrf va n cbg) I could include that and explain. If reasonably different I'll leave it np.

Comment: There you have it! :)